# Compare FASTQ reconstructions to mtDNA

Tags: fasta, fastq, mtdna

I have some doubts in how to proceed to compare ancient mtDNA with modern mtDNA. A little more context:

**The problem:**

I have some FASTQs associated with a given FASTA. They contain mtDNA. My goal is to extract the mtDNA from those FASTQs and compare with a reference mtDNA to calculate the average and SD of that difference.
I currently download the samples FASTA and FASTQs from AMTDB (https://amtdb.org/samples).
My final goal is to compare ancient mtDNA with modern mtDNA to analyze the deterioration based on the degradation patterns.

**What I'm lacking in knowledge:**

1. Does it make sense if I align the FASTQ with the corresponded downloaded FASTA? I mean, if the FASTA was already generated with those reads, wouldn't that be redundant?
2. Could I use an arbitrary mtDNA FASTA to align and compare? That would assume mtDNA in humans is very similar (I have doubts if that would be a safe assumption, since my goal is to compare those ancient samples with a modern and not damaged sample)
3. In any case, is there a recommended program to compare the results of the processing of the FASTQs with the reference FASTA?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and explain the relationship between these fastqs and fasta files you mention? You should probably also tell us what species you are working with, should we assume human?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.